# Can ColdFusion access a network drive while running under local system account?

Tags: coldfusion

We have a set of files that we need ColdFusion to copy to a network share.  However, we are unable to change the user that the ColdFusion service is running under, which means that ColdFusion does not have adequate permissions to access any network shares.  We do have a username and password that would give us access, but we cannot have the entire ColdFusion service running under that account.

Is there any way to do these file copy operations from within ColdFusion?  Possibly be spawning a cfthread under the new user, accessing the underlying java, or using some other third party component?  Our fallback is to create a batch file and run it from Windows Task Scheduler that copies all files in a local directory to the network share, but that's a suboptimal solution as it requires setup and maintenance outside of the CF codebase.

Comment: Spawning another thread wouldn't help because it's being run by the same CF instance. This'd be slightly overhead-heavy... but you could run a second CF instance with the correct perhaps, and have the only code it runs being a file-system-access proxy for the main CF instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is something that I have used in the past. It requires access to the `cfexecute` tag however. If you have access to running that tag (some hosting providers do not allow it) then you can do something like the following.

Map the network drive via a Window's share (note that any output is being written to the `netMessage` variable):
*This is where you would specify the remote username and password*

```
<cfexecute name="C:\WINDOWS\system32\net.exe"
    arguments="use \\#remoteServerName#\#remoteShareName#\ #remoteAccountPassword# /user:#remoteServerName#\#remoteAccountUsername#"
    variable="netMessage"
    timeout="30">
</cfexecute>
```

Copy the files to the network drive via the mapped drive that you just created (note that any output is being written to the `robocopyMessage` variable):
*I am using [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) here and suggest you look into it instead of just copy*

```
<cfexecute name="C:\WINDOWS\system32\robocopy.exe"
    arguments="#localDirectory# \\#remoteServerName#\#remoteShareName#\ #robocopyArguments#"
    variable="robocopyMessage"
    timeout="300">
</cfexecute>
```

Now cleanup by disconnecting the mapped network drive (note that any output is being written to the `netMessage` variable):

```
<cfexecute name="C:\WINDOWS\system32\net.exe"
    arguments="use \\#remoteServerName#\#remoteShareName#\ /d"
    variable="netMessage"
    timeout="30">
</cfexecute>
```

You could also put this code within `cfthread` tags if you wish.

Comment: That's a creative solution Miguel; thanks!  Unfortunately, while I'm getting no error messages back it's not working.  I'm unable to install any additional software, so I'm trying to use xcopy.  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot where the problem is occuring?  All variables are empty strings.

Comment: Please disregard my last question.  I just realized that this was a stupid mistake; I had a path with spaces and forgot to enclose it with quotes.  Once I did I started getting a message back from xcopy: "0 File(s) copied".  I'm going to work on this a bit now.

Comment: Just FYI but robocopy comes with Windows as well. No need to install new software. Remember to dump out those message variables while debugging. They will contain any messages being displayed to the "console".

Comment: I realized that after my last comment :).  I've been trying with robocopy, but it just hangs the request until the timeout period; not sure why.  I know the credentials are good as I have tried manually copying files in Windows Explorer using them.

Comment: What I would do for this is perform the steps I showed manually in a command window from that server. Then you will see any messages etc. Once you have the steps down then you just transfer that information into my examples above. It tends to be easier to debug that way.

Comment: You read my mind.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to that server.  I'm going to email someone who does shortly to see if they can give it a try.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem. I hope it works out for you. It has helped me in the past. Come back and let me know what you end up doing.

Comment: (Edit) @Nicholas - What version of CF?  Miguel-F - Does robocopy display any sort of confirmation screen that you have to suppress? That is a shot in the dark, but it was the cause of an apparent hang with some executables I have used.

Comment: @Leigh it depends on the options you use with the command. It can be verbose or nothing at all. The options are listed at the link I provided.

Comment: @Miguel-F - I missed the link while skimming on my phone ;-) What I was thinking of was some programs require an agreement to a license. So they display a prompt/popup - even from the command line, which is silly. When used in conjunction with cfexecute, it appears to hang because the program is waiting for a human to click agree/okay.  Now that I looked over the flags in the link, I do not think robocopy has anything like that. (I cannot test it out now). So my shot in the dark was way off.

Comment: @Leigh - no worries. Robocopy comes with Windows. No license stuff but I agree. Sometimes with cfexecute it can definitely get stuck at a prompt. In the comments I told the OP to test from the command prompt first and then once it's working add those commands to the example I provided. I think he is testing it out. Hopefully he will let us know how it goes

Comment: I finally received terminal access to the server and tracked down the problem.  I was adding a backslash to the end of directory names on both net use and robocopy commands, which resulted in errors.  After correcting the syntax everything began working.  Thank you again for all the help Miguel; this is a great trick to have on hand for when this need pops up (which seems to be every year or two).

Comment: Awesome glad it worked for you! Robocopy has LOTS of options. You should check them out (if you haven't already). One thing that has bitten me before is the number of retries on error. By default the number of retries is 1,000,000 (yes 1 million). No harm was done but it caused the `cfexecute` tag to timeout after a long time.  I have since always defined the number of retries to something more manageable when I run it.

Comment: *By default the number of retries is 1,000,000*  Holy cow.... Yes, a slightly more sane default sounds like a good idea ;-)